# Why are the standard errors the same for Anova + lsmeans results

Tags: r, anova, standard-error, lsmeans

I am working with a type 3 ANOVA + lsmeans. I was wondering why sometimes the standard error of all factor levels have the same value?

This is my dataset. var, SW, trt are my factors. RG is my metric y-variable.

```
trialdata<-structure(list(var = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
                       "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", 
                       "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
                       "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", 
                       "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
                       "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", 
                       "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
                       "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
                       "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
                       "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
                       "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", 
                       "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
                       "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), SW = c(28, 
                                                                                      28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 31, 31, 31, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 31, 31, 
                                                                                      31, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 31, 31, 31, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 
                                                                                      31, 31, 31, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 31, 31, 31, 28, 28, 28, 29, 
                                                                                      29, 29, 31, 31, 31, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 31, 31, 31, 28, 28, 
                                                                                      28, 29, 29, 29, 31, 31, 31, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 31, 31, 31, 
                                                                                      28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 31, 31, 31, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 31, 
                                                                                      31, 31, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 31, 31, 31, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 
                                                                                      29, 31, 31, 31, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 31, 31, 31, 28, 28, 28, 
                                                                                      29, 29, 29, 31, 31, 31, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 31, 31, 31, 28, 
                                                                                      28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 31, 31, 31, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 31, 31, 
                                                                                      31), trt = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                                                                                   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
                                                                                                   2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
                                                                                                   3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
                                                                                                   3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
                                                                                                   4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
                                                                                                   5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
                                                                                                   6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6), 
               RG = c(8, 7, 8, 7, 5, 8, 7, 5, 4, 7, 7, 5, 7, 5, 6, 7, 7, 
                      4, 9, 8, 6, 8, 6, 7, 8, 5, 7, 7, 6, 5, 7, 8, 7, 7, 7, 6, 
                      9, 7, 6, 8, 5, 8, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 8, 9, 7, 6, 9, 
                      6, 8, 8, 6, 7, 8, 7, 8, 4, 7, 6, 7, 6, 5, 6, 5, 4, 6, 8, 
                      7, 9, 7, 6, 7, 8, 5, 3, 8, 7, 5, 6, 6, 6, 4, 5, 7, 9, 5, 
                      8, 5, 7, 7, 4, 8, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8, 7, 6, 4, 6, 4, 5, 8, 6, 
                      7, 7, 5, 4, 7, 8, 7, 6, 6, 4, 6, 6, 8, 6, 7, 6, 8, 7, 8, 
                      6, 7, 5, 8, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9, 7, 7, 
                      6, 7, 8, 7, 7, 8, 7, 8, 8, 7, 7, 8)), row.names = c(NA, -162L
                      ), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This is my code to calculate the ANOVA and lsmeans:
The lsmeans are displayed in a letters display (cld).

```
#load libraries
library(readxl)
library(lme4)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)
library(car)
library(emmeans)
library(multcompView)
library(multcomp)

trialdata<-read_excel("Evaluation.xlsx",sheet=1,col_names=TRUE)

#factorize
trialdata[1:3]<-lapply(trialdata[1:3],as.character)

#make numeric
trialdata[4:4]<-lapply(trialdata[4:4],as.numeric)

#ANOVA; Lsmeans, CLD, ggplot
print(Anova(model<- lm(RG~SW+trt+var,data=trialdata),type="III",singular.ok = TRUE))
lsmeans<-emmeans(model,pairwise  ~trt)
clddata <- cld(lsmeans,
               alpha=0.05,
               Letters=letters,
               adjust="tukey")
clddata$.group<-gsub(" ", "",  clddata$.group, fixed = TRUE)

print(ggplot( data= clddata, aes(x=trt,y=emmean)) +
        geom_text(size=4,aes(y=emmean+SE*2.0,label=.group),position=position_dodge(0.9),angle=0,vjust=0.5, hjust=0.3 ) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), colour="black")+
        geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=emmean-SE, ymax=emmean+SE), width=.1,position=position_dodge(0.9))+
        geom_line(position=position_dodge(0.9))+
        geom_point(position=position_dodge(0.9)) +labs(y="RG", x = "", fill= "")+
        theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 20, b = 0, l = 0)))+
        theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size=16))+
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 10, r = 20, b = 0, l = 0)))+theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=16,angle=0)))
```

Here is the ggplot output, where you can see that the standard errors are all the same:
[image]

Here is the output of the lsmeans table:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. Could you use `dput` to share your data?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment. I used dput. Is it better now?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer by Russ Lenth, the *emmeans* package author, here, answers your question.  [Interpreting the standard error from emmeans - R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/369532/interpreting-the-standard-error-from-emmeans-r)